# Open a div on click for each tooltip in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, tooltip

I am trying to get a tooltip for each portion on a location map. Using the code below, I am getting the tool tip for as many portions as I want. But the next step is to give a link in each tooltip and it should open another which has more information.
Please suggest if I can do something in my code. Note: It should not be involve manually adding divs, divs should just be added as my tooltips are added (using variables).

```
<style>
body { 
    text-align: center; 
    font: 13px Arial,Helvetica;      
} 

/* Relative positioning*/ 
#wrapper { 
    position: relative; 
    margin: 10px auto 20px auto; 
    border: 1px solid #fafafa; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5); 
} 

/* Hide the original tooltips contents */ 
.pin { 
    display: none; 
} 

/* Begin styling the tooltips and pins */ 
.tooltip-up, .tooltip-down { 
    position: absolute; 
    background:url(mapimg.png); 
    width: 26px; 
    height: 15px; 
} 

.tooltip-down { 
    background-position: 0 -52px; 
} 

.tooltip { 
    display: none; 
    width: 180px; 
    cursor: ; 
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 12px; 
    left: 140px; 
    z-index: 999; 
    margin-left: -125px; 
    padding:15px; 
    color: #222; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7); 
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.7); 
    background: #fff1d3; 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff1d3), to(#ffdb90)); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff1d3, #ffdb90); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff1d3, #ffdb90); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff1d3, #ffdb90); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff1d3, #ffdb90); 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fff1d3, #ffdb90);          
} 

.tooltip::after { 
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -10px; 
    left: 50%;/* 
    margin-left: -90px; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff1d3; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right :10px solid transparent;*/ 
} 

.tooltip-down .tooltip { 
    bottom: 12px; 
    top: auto; 
} 

.tooltip-down .tooltip::after { 
    bottom: -10px; 
    top: auto; 
    border-bottom: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid #ffdb90; 
} 

.tooltip h2 { 
    font: bold 1.3em 'Trebuchet MS', Tahoma, Arial; 
    margin: 0 0 10px; 
} 

.tooltip ul { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none; 
}    

#pop1, #pop2 {
        display:none;  
    width: 180px; 
    cursor: ; 
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 12px; 
    left: 140px; 
    z-index: 999; 
    margin-left: -125px; 
    padding:15px; 
    color: #222; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    background: #fff1d3; 
} 
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // set the wrapper width and height to match the img size
        $('#wrapper').css({'width':$('#wrapper img').width(),
                          'height':$('#wrapper img').height()
        })

        //tooltip direction
        var tooltipDirection;

        for (i=0; i<$(".pin").length; i++)
        {               
            // set tooltip direction type - up or down             
            if ($(".pin").eq(i).hasClass('pin-down')) {
                tooltipDirection = 'tooltip-down';
            }
            else {
                tooltipDirection = 'tooltip-up';
            }

            // append the tooltip
            $("#wrapper").append("<div style='left:"+$(".pin").eq(i).data('xpos')+"px;top:"+$(".pin").eq(i).data('ypos')+"px' class='" + tooltipDirection +"'>\
                                                <div class='tooltip'>" + $(".pin").eq(i).html() + "</div>\
                                        </div>");
        }    

        // show/hide the tooltip
        $('.tooltip-up, .tooltip-down').mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).children('.tooltip').fadeIn(100);
            }).mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).children('.tooltip').fadeOut(100);
        })
    });
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <img width="920" height="450" src="image.jpg" alt="World continents">

    <div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="280" data-ypos="110">     
      tooltip 1 <br> 
      <b>Area:</b> 24 sft<br>
        <b>block:</b> 2 <a href="#">Click here for more info(need to give link here for new pop div..for all other tooltips)</a>
    </div>

    <div class="pin" data-xpos="280" data-ypos="135">      
       <b>Area 2</b><br/>     
    Area: 17 sft<br/>
        Population: 382,000,000
    </div>

    <div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="280" data-ypos="158">     
     <b>Area 3</b><br/>
      Area: 10<br/>
        <b>Population:</b> 731,000,000  <a href="#">Click here for more info(need to give link here for new pop div..for all other tooltips)</a>
    </div>

    <div class="pin" data-xpos="280" data-ypos="180">      
      <strong>Area 4</strong><br/>    
     Area: 30<br/>
        Population: 1,022,011,000 <a href="#">Click here for more info(need to give link here for new pop div..for all other tooltips)</a>
    </div>

    <div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="280" data-ypos="206">     
    <strong> tooltip 5  </strong><br/>
     Area : 43,820,000<br/>
        Population: 3,879,000,000 <a href="#">Click here for more info(need to give link here for new pop div..for all other tooltips)</a>
    </div>

    <div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="750" data-ypos="310">     
     <strong> tooltip 5 </strong><br/>
     Area : 43,820,000<br/>
        Population: 3,879,000,000 <a href="#">Click here for more info(need to give link here for new pop div..for all other tooltips)</a>
    </div>

    <div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="850" data-ypos="310">    
     <strong> tooltip 5 </strong><br/>
     Area : 43,820,000<br/>
        Population: 3,879,000,000 <a href="#">Click here for more info(need to give link here for new pop div..for all other tooltips)</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add a `div` after an anchor once the anchor is clicked, if the anchor is clicked again the `div` will be removed:

```
$('a').click(function()
{
    var currTag = $(this);
    if (currTag.next('div').attr('name'))
    {
        currTag.next('div').remove();
    }
    else
    {
        currTag.after("<div name='details'>Here's more information</div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: This displays the common information for all the a tags. I need different content and images in each divs and also initial div should disapper and show the new div presently your code displays the new div inside my previous dive wher the click here text is there

Comment: You will have to set a unique identifier or key in each div where you want the new div with details to appear. Using that identifier, you have to retrieve the details and add them to the new div. I would suggest you create an array containing details for each div and use the unique identifier or key in each div to access the array. Hope this helps.